c# Как проверить электронную подпись на квалифицированность и строить цепочку сертификации
подскажите, пожалуйста, как на c# проверить что сертификат является квалифицированным (КЭП). На что надо смотреть? Я так предполагаю, что КЭП в своей цепочки имеет 3 сертификата, самым первым идет сертификат от Минцифр, затем сертификат УЦ, и затем сертификат пользователя, а у НЭП эта цепочка будет состоять из 2-х сертификатов, будет отсутствовать сертификат Минцифр, так ли это и можно ли на это опираться или нужен какой-то другой подход?
И второй вопрос, если на ПК не установлены корневые сертификаты, то проверить цепочку не получится, но должен же быть способ строить цепочку онлайн без установки корневых на ПК, как это можно реализовать? Это нужно чтобы проверять сертификат на отозванность

Корневой сертификат должен быть установлен на комп, это основа доверия всей цепочке.

но ведь можно без этого как то проверить, что сертификат действует и не отозван. всякие же сервисы делают такие проверки, и не думаю что у них установлены все сертификаты всех УЦ

Доверие начинается с доверию к корневому сертификату. Можете его к себе на диск положить, куда угодно. Важно то, что у вас должна быть копия корневого сертификата, достоверность которой вас устраивает. А далее используя этот сертификат проверяете подпись сделующего сертификата в цепочке и т.д. по цепочке. Сертификат может быть отозван только тем, кем он выдан. То есть центр сертификации, выдающий сертификат, должен предоставить сервис валидации сертификатов. Это обычно какое-то OSCP API.
